# C# dataGridView show filename only, but open full path

Tags: c#, mysql

**Goal:**

- Show cell value as just the filename, not full path
- Selected cell value, open folder where file is located on click

**Current Code to load data grid view:**

```
    private void Form14_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int select = Convert.ToInt32(f9.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        // MySQL connection string
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
        {
            using (var mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"select file_attachment1, file_attachment2,file_attachment3,file_attachment4,file_attachment5,file_attachment6,file_attachment7,file_attachment8,file_attachment9,file_attachment10 from document_control  where id = " + select + "", conn))
            {
                using (var dataSet = new DataSet())
                {
                    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
                    dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Old File 1";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Old File 2";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Old File 3";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Old File 4";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Old File 5";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Old File 6";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Old File 7";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Old File 8";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Old File 9";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Old File 10";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Code to open the directory:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        int select = Convert.ToInt32(f9.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

        string file = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", " /select, " + file);
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No File Found...");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No record selected");
    }
}
```

**Desired Output:**

Instead of cells to show the full path, show just the filename, Like so: `test.csv`.

On button click, open the file location of full path.

**What I have tried:**

Have already altered mysqlDataAdapter query to use `substring_index` to get the filename, which achieves my first goal.

But, if I click `button1` file is non existent.. because it is not looking for full path.

**Question:**

What is a good method to achieve these 2 goals?

Currently struggling to understand, how I can display cells as filename. But in the background represent it as a full value. Where user will be able to open the full path name.

Comment: You can have a hidden column with full file path.

Comment: @Miamy, how can I select value to the right of the currently selected cell?

Comment: You can use `DataGridViewCell.ColumnIndex` property for the `CurrentCell`

Comment: If your files in the single row will have different locations, you should have 10 hidden columns, obviously. I would suggest to create hidden column with full path right after the visible one. So you always can to address it via `CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1`

Comment: Could you instead return a set of results, with a column for File Name and another column for File Path. The DGV would have one row per Old File. Do you need to "cross-tab" the Old Files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is that you get the name of the file in C # code and at the same time save the address in the cell property:

### Current Code to Load DGV:

```
private void Form14_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You previus code here ...
    // Here is you new modify code:
    using (var dataSet = new DataSet())
    {
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];

        for(int colidx=0; colidx<dataGridView1.Columns.Count; colidx++) // You have index from 0 to 9
        {
            // if you use C# 7 you use: 
            // dataGridView1.Columns[colidx].HeaderText = $"Old File {(colidx+ 1).ToString()};
            dataGridView1.Columns[colidx].HeaderText = "Old File " + (colidx+ 1).ToString();

            // The magic:
            for(int rowidx = 0; rowidx < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rowidx++)
            {
                string filepathcell = dataGridView1.Rows[rowidx].Cells[colidx].Value.ToString();
                // Only filename, remember: implements "using System.IO;" and this may launch exception, be careful
                dataGridView1.Rows[rowidx].Cells[colidx].Value = Path.GetFileName(filepathcell);
                // Save full pathfile:
                dataGridView1.Rows[rowidx].Cells[colidx].Tag = filepathcell;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is your modify code to open directory:

**Open Dir**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        // This is the only line modified
        string file = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Tag.ToString();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", " /select, " + file);
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No File Found...");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No record selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'` - I'll have a look into your code and see what is happening.

Comment: In what part ? because I dont see a asign a negative value to a index

Comment: it highlights this code: `dataGridView1.Columns[colidx].HeaderText = "Old File " + (colidx + 1).ToString();`

Comment: The for statement go from 0 to 9, How many columns your data returns ? because 0 to 9 is the same in the for that to do it manually

Comment: Or better, replace this line for better security     for(int colidx=0; colidx<dataGridView1.Columns.Count; colidx++) // You have index from 0 to columns count

Comment: It's definitely 0 -9. I'm confused myself haha! But this methods works as I have asked.